Using Sign in with Google in an embeddable iframe product
I've built a product that media publishers embed via iframe into their sites. Folks have asked for me to provide social login options, most notably, Google. Given that the product is relatively self serve and there are many sites with embeds on complete different URLs I'm struggling to implement Sign in with Google.
The Google popup is reading the page that embeds my iframe as the origin and I consistently run into redirect_uri_mismatch issues in the popup on button press regardless of whether I try to use implicit flow or auth-code flow.
The only solution I can think of is when someone attempts to sign in with Google, is having that button, on click, fully navigate them to a page on my domain to do the auth and redirect them back to the clients site on completion.
Is there another way to accomplish what I'm looking to do that doesn't take the user off the client site?
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    scope: 'profile email',
    flow: 'auth-code',
    ux_mode: 'popup',
    redirect_uri: 'https://example.com/integrations/google',
});

<button onClick={googleLogin}>Sign in with Google</button>

